# Lambda can't execute putjobSuccess for CodePipeline inside a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to create a Lambda function that works with CodePipeline. The issue is that it can't send the job success info to CodePipeline.
I'm using the javascript aws-sdk and the function putJobSuccessResult from the AWS.CodePipeline objects don't execute fine in production.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const codepipeline = new AWS.CodePipeline();

exports.config = (event, context) => {
  // Retrieve the Job ID from the Lambda action
  const jobId = event['CodePipeline.job'].id;

  return codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult({ jobId }).promise();
};
```

This code works fine locally when I put the jobId of my pipeline but when I upload the code on the AWS Console and run the pipeline, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is the IAM Configuration for the Lambda specific to CodePipeline part:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "codepipeline:PutJobSuccessResult",
                "codepipeline:PutJobFailureResult"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you have any ideas about why it doesn't work on the cloud ?

Comment: Does your pipeline have permissions to `lambda:InvokeFunction` and `lambda:ListFunctions`?

Comment: @Marcin Yes it have. The lambda execute well but timeout when try to execute the `putJobSuccessResult` function.

Comment: Is it in a VPC?

Comment: @Marcin Yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very likely reason why your **lambda in VPC** timeouts is that it has **no internet access** since it does not have public IP. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html):

> Connect your function to private subnets to access private resources. If your function needs internet access, use NAT. Connecting a function to a public subnet **does not give it internet access or a public IP address**.

To rectify the issue, the following **should be checked**:

- is lambda in a private subnet
- is there a NAT gateway/instance in a public subnet
- are route tables correctly configured from private subnet to the NAT device to enable internet access

Alternatively, can consider using (or check if exists) a [VPC interface endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/vpc-support.html#use-vpc-endpoints-with-codepipeline) for CodePiepline. The interface, if **correctly setup**, can enable access to the CodePipeline from lambda function without internet.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marcin, it works fine by creating an [interface endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html#create-interface-endpoint) for CodePipeline on my VPC